# Hacking an RC car controller using an Arduino to electronically control an RC car from computer

Tags: arduino, automotive, remote-control

I want to control an RC car from my computer so I can link my RC car with my racing wheel and pedals. To do this I was planning on modifying a dumbo X6 controller and connect an Arduino to it by swapping the potentiometers on it with some transistors instead which I can control from the Arduino and in turn from my PC via serial.

I don't know much about electronics and I don't know if this will work at all or if it's a bad way to go about it.

If it is possible, I don't know how to check if my transistors would work in mimicing the potentiometers.

Answer (score 1):

Although I am not familiar with the inner workings of the controller, it is possible for you to use transistors in this setup. But, ultimately you need to figure out the current requirements and voltage range of the the potentiometer output.

If the current requirements and the voltage range is within the Arduino's output, you can wire an Arduino to some type of circuitry that produces a desired DC voltage (E.g., a PWM output and an RC filter, although ripple may cause an issue) that is then wired directly to the potentiometer output. No transistor necessary.

If the current requirements or the voltage requirements are not met, you need to do the above with an active amplifier circuit to provide higher current or voltage to the load. A single transistor amplifier (E.g., a common-emitter amplifier) suffices but you must bias it properly, of course. If you need to get close to zero volts, you will have your lower-voltage supply rail of the amplifier be less than your zero volt reference (I.e., negative) for it to stay "linear" in the voltage range.

There are a countless number of resources to figure out how to do the above so a quick google search will always be helpful in determining what is required for designing your circuit. Good luck!

Comment: thanks for the response
I'll have to wait for the controller to arrive before I can test the range of the pot but I have read in a related question your suggested method which does seem better.